# Is it Possible to Retrieve the Original File Location of a File Selected through Shiny Parameters in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

When selecting a file through a parameter, **Shiny** copies the selected file to a temporary location so that the original filepath and name are lost. Is there a way to see which file was selected, so that people reviewing the work can verify that the correct file was used?

I have looked around for an answer and the only related post I can find is this:
https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/919#issuecomment-415305036

For the time being, I will continue using `file.choose()` which allows me to track the file path of the selected input file.

Comment: The `input$inputid$datapath` will keep the original file name, but because shiny runs in a web browser, the web browser does not provide the original file path for security reasons. You cannot get the full original path.

Comment: Concur on the "security reasons" point, that's the key: being able to infer something from the user's computer that is not explicitly provided is considered a bad thing. For instance, if the original file was uploaded from a directory called `"C:/Users/Doobie1969/Clients/BigCompany/ProjectOrion/somedata.csv"`, simple social engineering suggests that the remote user's login account is `Doobie1969`, they are contracted by `BigCompany` on a project named `ProjectOrion`. Perhaps none of that is required by your app.

Answer (score 2):

This problem came up again and I figured out a workaround that I figured I would share. Basically, I rely on `tk_choose.files()` from the "tcltk" library. I created an action button that calls that command and then I use the `assign()` command to move it into my global environment. This makes it possible to show the complete file path of the selected file within your RMD's output file.

```
library(shiny)
library(tcltk)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny Example"),
  helpText("Location of Example Input File"),
  verbatimTextOutput("printFilePath"),
  actionButton("inputFileButton", "Select File")
)

server <- function(input, output) {      
  observeEvent(input$inputFileButton, {
    selectedFilePath <-
      tk_choose.files(caption = "Select the Example Input File")
    output$printFilePath <- renderPrint(selectedFilePath)
    assign("selectedFilePath", selectedFilePath, .GlobalEnv)
  })      
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Based on my research, nobody else has ever posted this workaround, so I'm hoping someone else will find it useful.